# Sharing React web app content to Instagram

Tags: reactjs, instagram-api

I have a React-based web application and I would like to allow users to share content to Instagram, either as a story or in their feed. I've already generated a snapshot of the HTML I want to share using the html2canvas package and stored it in a state.

When I checked the documentation for Instagram's API, it appears that they only support mobile-built applications (source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/). As a result, I realize that sharing is not possible on a desktop. To work around this, I'm planning to hide the share button when users are on a desktop.

One alternative solution I'm considering is allowing users to download the snapshot I created. However, I read that this would only save the image in their downloads folder on mobile devices, rather than in their gallery.

I'm still new to this and would appreciate any feedback or suggestions on how I can accomplish this. How can I allow users to share content to Instagram from my React web application, taking into consideration the limitations of Instagram's API and the desktop environment? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this? I have a similar problem. Please let me know .

Comment: I did a bit of digging around on the topic and as far as I could find out is that if we want to interact with mobile devices to this degree we need a native application. You can share stuff more easily from a desktop app to WhatsApp, but Instagram supports only native. Also, to access the phone's gallery you'd need to have a native app as well. My work around all this is create an informative UI so that users can take the screenshot themselves and share wherever and however they want. I've added the branding I need to the snapshot, so it will have the needed effect. Hope this helps a bit :)